# Inno Setup: Copying files (to System32) takes long time

Tags: installation, inno-setup, redistributable, system32

Our software project uses Inno Setup to roll it out to the customers. We found on some target computers it takes a long time for some DLLs to be copied to the system32 directory (about 2 minutes per file). The first intention was this files are hardly monitored by the virus scanner. But it has nothing to do with the certain files itself. If I change the order of the DLLs to be copied - always the first 3 files takes this long time. Because of this behaviour it's out of question that the virus scanner finds something peculiar within the files.

I found another strange thing: In the `PrepareToInstall` function the installer executes `vcredist_x86_vc++_2013.exe`. If I exchange the file to another executable file that is packed within the installation the problem persists. But if I disable the execution of the pre-requisite installation file later all DLLs are copied within a fraction of a second.

Summarised: If I copy a prerequisite file (doesn't matter what) later on the first 3 or 4 copied DLLs needing a very long time to be copied.

Does somebody here find an similar problem or knows a way to solve this. Any help is welcome.

Other information:

- Its the same for both Win7 or Win10
- The user owns local administrative rights

Comment: It still sounds like an antivirus issue. Did you try to turn off the antivirus?

Comment: In my mind is also the idea it comes from virusprotection. But i stopped all services and killed all tasks from Sophos and the extra time is stiil there. The problem does not depend from a certain file that is copied to the target system. It does not matter if I substitute it. This is whimsical too.

Comment: Did you turn off Windows Defender as well?

Comment: "Check apps and files" of Windows Defender is turned off.

Comment: I have seen this too on numerous occasions and with numerous different customers. It's always and only when copying files to the System32 directory. Unfortunately, I have never managed to work out the exact pattern or cause, but I don't believe it's Anti-Virus related.

Comment: I added the System32 detail to the title. Hopefully it creates a bit more attention

Comment: @Matthias Are the files you are copying into the System32 directory code signed? I have just realised that, in my case, the DLLs are very old and consequently are not code signed. I have just code signed them to see if this makes any difference. However, it may be a while before I can say for sure, given the intermittent nature of this.

Comment: @Robert: No, the files are not code signed too. Also I'm in doubt it's up to the files itself. As I mentioned if I change the order of the files allways the first three files taking ages to be copied or wathever the installer does in that time. The rest of the files are processed in a blink.

Comment: @Matthias That's interesting. Are you able to reproduce this consistently? That's always been the problem for us, we see it occasionally on a customer site, but do not get a chance to investigate it and cannot reproduce it in house.